# Read Mocha json report and publish the result to a Test Management tool

Tags: mocha.js

I am running my mocha tests with json reporter enabled.
I am required to publish my results to a Test Management tool once my suite is completed using an API.
For that i am trying to read my output json file and get to know which tests are passed/failed. Accordingly, I am creating a API Payload to publish the results on a Test Management tool.
For that, i have included my code block to read the output json in the 'After' Block of the test file but the problem is that the report is not generated when it is processing the 'After' block.

Below is the sample code

**Test.js:**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args');
const request = require('request').defaults({rejectUnauthorized: false});
const fs = require('fs');

const optionDefinitions = [
    {name: 'file', alias: 'f', type: String},
    {name: 'format', alias: 'm', type: String, defaultValue: 'newman-json'},
    {name: 'usetestcaseid', alias: 'i', type: String},
    {name: 'regex', alias: 'r', type: String, defaultValue: /^[^\d]*(\d+)/},
    {name: 'parentid', alias: 'p', type: String},
    {name: 'parenttype', alias: 't', type: String, defaultValue: 'root'},
    {name: 'help', alias: 'h', type: Boolean},
];

const options = commandLineArgs(optionDefinitions);



var assert = require('assert');
it('12345_should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
      assert.equal([1, 2, 3].indexOf(4), -1);
    });
    
after(function publishReport() {
    // runs once after the last test in this block
    var outputReport = fs.readFileSync('filename.json', 'utf8');
    var rpt=JSON.parse(outputReport);
    console.log(rpt);
    var passedCases = rpt.passes;
    console.log(passedCases);
  });
```

Config File:

```
{
  "spec": "test/**/test1.js",
  "reporter": "mochajs/json-file-reporter",
  "reporter-option": [
    "output=filename.json"
  ]
}
```

Could anyone please suggest me like where i need to exactly put my code on Mocha so that i can read the output report file once generated and publish the results?

Answer (score 0):

The only guarantee `mocha` (and its reporters) give, is that output files exist *after* exit of `mocha process`.

So, you have to put your code into separate script (upload.js, let's say) and run test suite like this (entry in package.json):

```
"tests-and-upload-results:": "mocha ; node ./upload.js"
```

All hooks are executed in scope of test run and reporters *in* general do not generate reports until whole test run is completed.

Comment: Thanks @Zbigniew. As suggested i ve created a separate .js file to read the json report and publish the results. Now, my scripts part in package.json looks like "scripts": {
 "test": "mocha",
 "tests-and-upload-results": "npm test ./publishResultsToqTest.js"
  } but when i run npm test only the test is running, publishResultsToqTest.js is not getting executed. Am i missing something?